# Halve the falses

Tags: code-golf, array

## Task

Given a **non-empty** array of `0` and `1`, halve the lengths of the runs of `0`.

## Input

An array of `0` and `1`. Acceptable format:

- Real array in your language
- Linefeed-separated string of `0` and `1`
- Contiguous string of `0` and `1`
- Any other reasonable format

For example, the following three inputs are all acceptable:

- `[1, 0, 0, 1]`
- `"1\n0\n0\n1"` (where `\n` is a linefeed U+000A)
- `"1001"`

You may assume that the runs of `0` will have **even length**.

## Output

An array of `0` and `1`, in the acceptable formats above.

## Testcases

```
input ↦ output
[1,0,0,1,0,0,1] ↦ [1,0,1,0,1]
[1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1] ↦ [1,1,0,1,1,0,1]
[1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1] ↦ [1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1]
[1,1,1] ↦ [1,1,1]
[0,0,1] ↦ [0,1]
[0,0] ↦ [0]
[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0] ↦ [1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0]
```

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest answer in bytes wins.

[Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.

Comment: In the last testcase, don't the runs of zeroes not have even length?

Comment: @OldBunny2800 Read the test case carefully; the 0-runs have lengths 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, and 2.

Comment: Can we take `true` and `false` instead of `1` and `0`?

Comment: @Cyoce which language?

Comment: @LeakyNun Ruby, which considers `0` to be truthy.

Comment: @Cyoce I suggest not.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino oh, I took "even" to mean "the same length", not "mathematically even" lol

Comment: Can we use different input and output formats?

Comment: @Challenger5 I don't see any point to that, but yes.

Comment: @LeakyNun It helps with CJam because arrays are displayed with all their elements concatenated together, and it would cost me a byte to uneval.

Answer (score 32):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 4 bytes

```
00
0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@29gwGXw/7@hoaEBEBiCaRAyROIAAA)

Comment: This one will be hard to beat.

Comment: @Adám I'd say impossible to beat.

Comment: Works in [QuadR](https://github.com/abrudz/QuadRS) too!

Answer (score 14):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
00¤.:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@29gcGiJntX//4aGhgZAYAimQcgQiQMA)

**Explanation**

```
00     # push 00
  ¤    # tail, pushes 0
   .:  # replace
```

Comment: That was easy; why didn't I think of that?

Comment: `00` is weird behavior...

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer: Sequential digits are concatenated to form a number, so `11` is eleven and not `1,1`. A side effect of that is that `00` becomes `00` instead of `0,0` :)

Comment: @Emigna I'd have expected it to become `0` or `0 0` instead, but whatever.

Comment: `¤` can also be `N`

Answer (score 9):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 33 bytes

```hs
f(0:0:r)=0:f r
f(x:r)=x:f r
f e=e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@5@mYWBlYFWkaWtglaZQxJWmUQHiVEA4Cqm2qf9zEzPzFGwVCooy80oUVBTSFKINdUDQAAoNdRB8Q7gIVpnY/wA) Usage: `f[1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1]`. Iterates over the list and replaces two consecutive zeros by one zero.

Comment: I feel that this can be forked to Prolog

Answer (score 8):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 35 bytes

```
f(char*s){while(*s)putchar(*s),*s++-48?:s++;}
```

48 is the ascii code of '0'

better version  43 bytes as suggested by Neil

```
f(char*s){while(*s)putchar(*s),s+=2-*s%2;}
```

another one 40 byte this time (again as suggested by  Neil &  VisualMelon) :)

```c
f(char*s){for(;*s;s+=50-*s)putchar(*s);}
```

and then 35 bytes thanks to Khaled.K

```c
f(char*s){*s&&f(s+50-putchar(*s));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#@5@mkZyRWKRVrFmtVaymlqZRrG1qoFtQWgIS1QAKa1rX/s/MK1HITczM09DkquZSSNNQMjAwBCIgADNAwDDGQEnTmqv2PwA)

Comment: Would `s+=2-*s%2` work?

Comment: yes it would, thanks I'll edit the response accordingly

Comment: If I've counted correctly I think `for(;*s;s+=2-*s%2)putchar(*s);` saves another byte.

Comment: What would be wrong with `s+=50-*s`?  Not done C for ages and don't want to embarrass myself by invoking undefined behaviour (coming from C# where there is none)

Comment: Looking at the `putchar` docs, can you do `f(char*s){for(;*s;s+=50-putchar(*s));}` ?

Comment: You can save 5 bytes by making it recursive `f(char*s){*s&&f(s+50-putchar(*s));}`

Answer (score 7):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 8 bytes

```
s/00/0/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/sed#@1@sb2Cgb6Cf/v@/oYEBCHEZgkgkFpgAsg25QGIGBgA)

Comment: @boboquack Doesn't work, since it would always replace a run of `0`s with `0`.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer No, it does just halve the length of runs of `0`'s: https://tio.run/##K05N@f@/WN/AQN9AP/3/fwMwAAA

Answer (score 6):

## Octave, 22 bytes

```
@(s)strrep(s,'00','0')
```

[**Verify all test cases here.**](https://tio.run/#TAaXw)

This is an anonymous function taking a string on the format `'1001000011'` as input, and replaces two consecutive zeros with a single zero.

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 28 bytes

```hs
f(h:t)=h:f(drop(1-h)t)
f e=e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@5@mkWFVommbYZWmkVKUX6BhqJuhWaLJlaaQapv6PzOvoLSkWMFWITraUMcACKFkrA6QDxPBLgZnQcVBNEwdkIaJglUh9KDYgmIakkxsLBdXbmJmHtBdBUWZeSUKKgq5iQUKaQoQ5/4HAA)

Recursively takes the first element, dropping the second one if the first one is zero, until the list of empty. If the first entry is `h`, then the first `1-h` are dropped from the remainder.

Answer (score 6):

## Java, 50 bytes

```java
String f(String s){return s.replaceAll("00","0");}
```

[**Try Online**](http://ideone.com/2lMKHM)

Comment: A very good input choice! By the way, if you're interested in switching to a Java 8+ solution, you could use a lambda: `s->s.replaceAll("00","0")`.

Comment: Even better, use `replace` instead of `replaceAll` to save 3 bytes

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart `replace` will only replace the first occurrence

Comment: @Khaled.K in javascript, yes. In java, it replaces all occurrences

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart is indeed correct, both `replace` and `replaceAll` replace all occurrences. The difference is that `replaceAll` supports regex. To replace the first occurrence there is the `replaceFirst` method (also supporting regex). I personally think Java's `replace` is the worst-named method there is in Java. Better would be if `replace` was called `replaceAll` and `replaceAll` was called `replaceAllWithRegex` or something along those lines.. :/

Answer (score 6):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>7 6</s> 5 bytes

```
d'0²0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@5@ibnBok8H//0qGBgYgpAQA)

Simply replaces each run of two zeroes in the input by one zero. Uses string input (i.e. `"1001001"`).

Comment: Nice! You don't even need the `'` I think

Comment: Ooh, you can save another byte by replacing `"00"` with `'0²` :-)

Comment: Well, that's weird. Thanks though!

Answer (score 6):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 4 bytes

```
fG=¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8X@au@2hnf///4@ONtQxAEIoGasD5MNEsIvBWVBxEA1TB6RhomBVCD0otqCYhiQTGwsA)

**How?**
The [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk) `scanl` command (`G`) applies a function to each element of a list and the result-so-far.  The initial result-so-far is set to the first element.

In this case, used with the `eq` (`=`) function, it checks whether each element is equal to the result-so-far.  For runs of `1`, this will always output `1` (truthy).  Now, the first of any run of `0`s will be `0` (falsy), of course; then, the next result will be `1` (since `0` is equal to the result-so-far), and then `0`, and so on, alternating `0`s at odd positions in the run and `1`s at even positions, until the end of the run.  Since there are always an even number of `0`s in each run, then last result-so-far must be `1`: so, when we enter the next run of `1`s, the first result will be `1` (truthy) again, and so on...

So: runs of `0`s get alternating `0` and `1`, and runs of `1`s always get `1`, and we just need to `filter` (`f`) the input list (`¹`) by this.

Answer (score 5):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 13 bytes

```
/oe00/
@iS0e\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/alice#@6@fn2pgoM/lkBlskBrz/7@hoaEBEBiCaRAyROIAAA)

#### Explanation

```
/.../
@...\
```

This is a simple template for linear programs which operate entirely in Ordinal mode. The initial `/` reflects the IP to move south east and then it bounces diagonally up and down through the code until the mirrors at the end. Those simply offset the position by one so that on the way back the IP traverses the remaining cells. Reading the code in this zigzag fashion it becomes:

```
ie00e0So@
```

This is a simple string substitution:

```
i   Read all input.
e   Push an empty string.
00  Append two zeros to create the string "00".
e   Push an empty string.
0   Append a zero to create the string "0".
S   Substitute all occurrences of "00" in the input with "0".
o   Output the result.   
@   Terminate the program.
```

There are a few other ways to push the two strings, e.g. `'00'0` or `e000t`, but I haven't found anything that beats 5 bytes there (and I'd have to shave off two bytes to be able to shorten the program).

Comment: Looks like you fell in love with Alice recently...

Comment: @LeakyNun Please don't tell my wife...

Comment: @MartinEnder I'm gonna tell that to Mrs. Ender!

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
ṣ1j1,1m2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/9w52LDLEMdw1yj////A2kgNIBCQx0E3xAuglUGAA)

Possibly other answers in languages without a `.replace()` or similar could use this trick.

**Explanation**

```
ṣ1j1,1m2 - (duplicates the 1s, then halves all lengths)
ṣ1       - split by the element 1
  j1,1   - join the elements with the two-element list 1,1
      m2 - get every second element
```

Answer (score 5):

## Perl 5, 7+1(-p flag)=8 bytes

```
<>if/0/
```

Takes input as newline separated numbers. Skips the next line if it sees a zero.

Answer (score 5):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), <s>8</s> 6 bytes

```
n;/0/d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/P89a30A/5f9/Ay4DLkMwNIBCw3/5BSWZ@XnF//VTUsv0i0tSMvMA)

Takes a linefeed-separated string of `0` and `1`.

`n` skips a line, and `/0/d` deletes a line if it has a zero in it. This has the net effect of deleting every `0` on an even-numbered line. Since any even-length contiguous list of `0` has the same number of even-numbered and odd-numbered lines, this has the effect of halving the length of every run of `0`.

Answer (score 5):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 4 bytes

```
òf0x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@394U5pBxf//BkBgCAQwEsGHAAA)

```
ò    ' Recursively (until we error)
 f0  ' Go to the next zero (errors when there are no zeros left)
   x ' Delete it
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
¹‘ƭƇ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///QzkcNM46tPdb@/3D7o6Y1kf//R3NFG@oYACGUjNUBCcCEcAjCWTAJMAOuFMiAS4BVIvSh2IViIpIMUHMsAA)

### Explanation

```
¹‘ƭƇ   Main monadic link
   Ƈ   Filter by
  ƭ      Every time this is called, switch between
¹          doing nothing and
 ‘         adding 1
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 42 bytes

```
[0,0|T]*[0|R]:-T*R.
[H|T]*[H|R]:-T*R.
H*H.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/prolog-swi#@x9toGNQExKrFW1QExRrpRuiFaTHFe0BFvFAiHhoeej9/x9tqAOCBlBoqIPgG8JFsMrEakXocZUXZZakakRoAgA)

Comment: A prolog answer, but not what I expected...

Comment: Nice trick to use the `*` operator.

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, 26

```
<?=strtr($argn,["00"=>0]);
```

simply replace all `00` by `0`.

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 5 bytes

```
FFOZt
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@@/m5h9V8v9/tKGOARBCyVgA)

#### Explanation

This is similar to Stewie Griffin's [Octave answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/118609/36398):

```
FF     % Push [0 0]
O      % Push 0
Zt     % Implicitly take input. Replace [0 0] by 0. Implicitly display
```

---

## 8 bytes

```
vy~f2L)(
```

This avoids the string/array replacement builtin.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@19WWZdm5KOp8f9/tKGOARBCyVgA)

#### Explanation

Consider input `[1,0,0,1,0,0,1]` as an example:

```
v      % Concatenate stack (which is empty): pushes []
       % STACK: []
y      % Implicit input. Duplicate from below
       % STACK: [1,0,0,1,0,0,1], [], [1,0,0,1,0,0,1]
~f     % Negate, find: gives indices of zeros
       % STACK: [1,0,0,1,0,0,1], [], [2,3,5,6]
2L     % Push [2,2,1i]. As an index, this is interpreted as 2:2:end
       % STACK: [1,0,0,1,0,0,1], [], [2,3,5,6], [2,2,1i]
)      % Reference indexing. This selects the even-indexed entries
       % STACK: [1,0,0,1,0,0,1], [], [3,6]
(      % Assignment indexing. This deletes the specified entries
       % (assigns them the empty array). Implicitly display
       % STACK: [1,0,1,0,1]
```

Answer (score 4):

## Lua, 33 bytes

```
print((io.read():gsub("00","0")))
```

Takes a string via input and condenses double zeros. Easy.

Answer (score 4):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), <s>12</s> 10 bytes

*2 bytes saved thanks to [Martin Ender](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-ender)*

```
i.h%.7%$io
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/alice#@5@pl6GqZ66qkpn//7@hoaEBEBiCaRAyROIAAA)

#### Explanation

This is a 1-D code operating in cardinal mode, so it's easy to follow its flow:

```
i                   Read a byte from input (pushes -1 on EOF)
 .h                 Duplicate it and add 1 to the copy
   %                Compute n%(n+1). This will exit with an error on n==-1
                    and return n for any non-negative n.
    .7%             Duplicate the input again and compute its value modulo 7
                    This returns 6 for '0' (unicode value 48) and 0 for '1'
                    (unicode value 49)
       $i           If this last result was not 0, input another number.
                    This ignores every other '0' in the input
                    and moves to the following number (another '0')
         o          Output the last byte read

                    At the end, wrap back to the beginning of the line
```

Comment: You can actually save two more bytes with `i.h%...`

Comment: @MartinEnder you're an evil person, going around teaching people to play dirty... :D

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>26</s> 21 bytes

Takes the input as a string and returns a string.

```
s=>s.replace(/00/g,0)
```

---

### Try It

```js
f=
s=>s.replace(/00/g,0)
i.addEventListener("input",_=>o.innerText=f(i.value))
console.log(f("1001001")) // "10101"
console.log(f("110011001")) // "1101101"
console.log(f("11001110011")) // "110111011"
console.log(f("111")) // "111"
console.log(f("001")) // "01"
console.log(f("00")) // "0"
console.log(f("11100001111001001100111100100")) // "1110011110101101111010"
```

```html
<input id=i><pre id=o>
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Java](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>131</s> 123 bytes

```java
int[]f(int[]a){int c=0,i=0,l=a.length;for(int x:a)c+=1-x;int[]r=new int[l-c/2];for(c=0;c<l;c+=2-a[c])r[i++]=a[c];return r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#bY89bsMwDIV3n0KjBNtqnLGqhh6gU0ZDA6vargpFNig6TWD47K7k9GcpCOFR5HvAx2l@9c4y6yFG9gIuLJsL1Jqe7wJiScqsPlQuPa9B@i4M9K76EbOFXR9B2FI39VXtCdSh@2S59bV9OJrdmPLKPnmVjMcaWmsEtq4sjc69wo5mDAzVuk13nEhASS6je2PnBMVPhC4MiQeHKJbidIvUneU4k5zSgnzgH3ABOZPz8hkRblHSeA/xzJMv40L2/AfOLE2V6/BdTfX3b34n/25WIYQq1mLdvgA)

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 24 bytes

```
StringReplace["00"->"0"]
```

A function that expects a string of `"0"`s and `"1"`s and returns a similar string. Self-explanatory syntax. Mathematica has lots of transformation builtins; the key is to use one that transforms every relevant subexpression (unlike `/.`) but only passes through the expression once (unlike `//.`).

Answer (score 3):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 5 bytes

```
aR00i
```

Takes a string of 0s and 1s. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/McjAIPP///@GhoYGQGAIpkHIEIkDAA)

#### Explanation

Beating Jelly? Inconceivable!

```
a      Take the first command-line argument
 R     and replace
  00   00 (an integer literal, so it doesn't need quotes)
    i  with i (variable preinitialized to 0)
       Autoprint
```

Comment: Not beating Jelly anymore ;)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 21 bytes

```r
function(n)n[n+1:0>0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNPMy86T9vQysDOIPZ/mkayhqGOARAaamr@BwA)

Comment: Ah, this better leverages the fact that runs of zero are even length! Very nice.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
ɖ=Tİ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCLJlj1UxLAiLCIiLCJbMSwxLDAsMCwxLDEsMSwwLDAsMCwwLDEsMCwwLDFdIl0=) Port of [Dominic van Essen's Husk answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241062/100664). See that for a more detailed explanation of how this works.

```
ɖ    # Scan by
 =   # Equal to the current result?
     # For runs of 1s, this is 1,
     # For runs of 0s this alternates between 1 and 0
  Tİ # Keep only items wihtt a 1 in the previous list
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 10 bytes

```
ḅ{cẹ|ḍh}ᵐc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@/9wR2t18sNdO2se7ujNqH24dULy///RhjqGOgZACKdj/0cBAA)

Not sure this is optimal yet…

#### Explanation

This exploits the bug that `c` on a list of integers that has leading zeroes will fail.

```
ḅ               Blocks; group consecutive equal elements together
 {     }ᵐ       Map on each block:
  c               It is possible to concatenate the block into an int (i.e. it contains 1s)
   ẹ              Split it again into a list of 1s
    |             Else
     ḍh           Dichotomize and take the head
         c      Concatenate the blocks into a single list
```

Comment: How is that a bug?

Comment: @LeakyNun We should be able to concatenate `[0,0,4,2]` into `42`. Leading zeroes make it fail right now because it's here to prevent infinite leading zeroes when the Input is a variable, but here the Input is fully grounded so that limitation shouldn't exist.

Comment: Would you write a Prolog answer?

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/) (list I/O), 36 bytes

```python
f=lambda l:l and l[:1]+f(l[2-l[0]:])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@59mm5OYm5SSqJBjlaOQmJeikBNtZRirnaaRE22kmxNtEGsVq/k/Lb9IIUchMy/aUMcACKFkrA6QDxPBLgZnQcVBNEwdkIaJglUh9KDYgmIakkysFRdnQVFmXokC0K2a/wE)

Recursively takes the first element, then removes the remaining one if the first one was zero.

---

**38 bytes:**

```python
lambda l:eval(`l`.replace('0, 0','0'))
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#S7ON@Z@TmJuUkqiQY5ValpijkZCToFeUWpCTmJyqoW6go2CgrqNuoK6p@T8tv0ghRyEzL9pQxwAIoWSsDpAPE8EuBmdBxUE0TB2QhomCVSH0oNiCYhqSTKwVF2dBUWZeiUKaRo7mfwA) This takes a Python list and outputs a Python list by doing replacement on its string representation. String I/O would allow a more direct and shorter solution, such as

```python
lambda s:s.replace('00','0')
```

for `'1001'`  format.

Comment: The first answer with format specified, nice.

Comment: String I/O *is* allowed. `lambda s:s.replace('00','0')` should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 11 bytes

```
/00/a//a/0/<input goes here>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/slashes#@69vYKCfqA9EBvr//wMA)

Fun fact: `/00/0/<input>` won't work, because it reduces `0000` to `0`. Hence the `a`-substitute.

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, 24 bytes

```
@set/ps=
@echo %s:00=0%
```

Takes input on STDIN. Somewhat competitive for once.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 9 bytes

```apl
'00'⎕R'0'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/apl-dyalog#@5/2qG2CuoGB@qO@qUHqBur/H3W0AUWqH7VNNDc0M3jUs@3Qike9fUCiY8aj3l1ABGKuBPLUDQzVgeyevUDpR71b9dUf9c5Tr1V41DtXISM1pyC1SCGtNC@5JDM/T6EkXyEztyC/qETBK9jfT0chsaAgpxIhDUSpickZCpl5BaUlQNm8FIX80hIgG6z8f5oC0E0K5lzRhjoGQAglY0F8mAh2MTgLKg6iYeqANEwUrAqhB8UWFNOQZGIB)

Comment: It says `DOMAIN ERROR: I-Beam function 7160 has been withdrawn`

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp, SBCL, <s>48</s> 32 bytes

*-16 bytes thanks to Julian Wolf*

```
(format t"~{~[0~*~;1~]~}"(read))
```

input:

```
(1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0)
```

output:

```
1001110
```

#### Explanation

We read input list.
List is used in `format` function.
We loop through it outputting `1` if element is `1` and outputting `0` and skipping next element of list for `0`.

Comment: Using `~[` rather than `~:[` lets you index with 0 and 1 directly, which should save you a bunch of bytes

Comment: @JulianWolf Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, <s>41</s> 40 bytes

```rb
->a{a.each_index{|i|a[i]>0||a[i..i]=[]}}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
Œg¹m2$S?€F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@390UvqhnblGKsH2j5rWuP3//99QBwQNoNBQB8E3hItglQEA)

**Explanation**

```
Œg¹m2$S?€F
Œg          - Group runs of equal elements
        €   - To each run...
      S?    - If sum is truthy,
  ¹         -   return the run as it is
   m2$      - Else return every second element of the run.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [BitCycle](https://github.com/dloscutoff/esolangs/tree/master/BitCycle), <s>18</s> <s>17</s> 15 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes via a clever rearrangement by [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king)*

```
?ABv
  +\!
 ^\<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8osSa5Mzkn9/9/e0amMS0FBO0aRSyEuxub///@GBmAApAwNwWwA)

#### Algorithm

Take two bits of the input at a time. Output the first one. Discard the second one if it is 0 and output it if it is 1.

Because we are guaranteed that all runs of 0s have even length, this approach will always discard half of the 0s from each run:

```
00 -> 0x
10 01 -> 1x 01
10 0  -> 1x 0
```

#### Implementation

The input bitstring comes in at the source `?` and is directed into the `A` collector, which in turn dumps its output into the `B` collector. Each time the `B` collector opens, the bits are directed through the two splitters `\`, which split off the first and second bits. The first bit goes east, straight into the sink `!` to be output. The second bit passes through the now-deactivated first splitter, hits the second splitter, and goes north into the `+`, which sends a 0 bit left (west) and off the playfield, but sends a 1 bit right (east) into the sink `!` to be output.

Meanwhile, the rest of the bits pass through both splitters and back into the `A` collector. Once they are all there, `A` opens and the cycle starts over. This loop continues until all bits are disposed of.

Comment: @JoKing And here I thought I had it as tight as possible! How are you so good at this language? :^D

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s><sup>8</sup></s> 7 bytes

```
ṁ?IĊ2←g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@HORnvPI11Gj9ompP///z/aUMcACCEkmBULAA)

might be shorter with strings.

-1 byte from Zgarb.

### Explanation

```
ṁ?Io←½←g
       g group equal runs of elements
ṁ        map each group to function, and concatenate
 ?    ←  if first element is truthy
  I      leave as is
   o←½   else remove the second half
```

Comment: You can use `Ċ2` to remove every second element.

Comment: @JoKing updated

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 18 bytes

```
[ "00""0"replace ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VUs7DsIwDN17iqecwJ2Q4ACIhQUxoQ5RZCqL4FhpFrh8aFIGkKzn9737UFKu18vpfNxjsSiliM6YWTn7KG9fJOkCSXhwVo44DIMbidq5lbX/xzt01XBLiDaDqDe@8/FHuHpDqzlymS36wJhWy7JowYSQnpYWxg7qzeKrfgA)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 29 bytes

```r
function(n)n[n|cumsum(!n)%%2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNPMy86rya5NLe4NFdDMU9TVdUo9n@aRrKGoY4BEBpqav4HAA)

Input as list of `0` and `1` or T/F

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, <s>24</s> 22 bytes

<sup>Saved 2 bytes thanks to Taylor Raine seeing what should have been obvious.</sup>

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"00",0)
```

Inputs is a contiguous string of `0` and `1` in cell `A1`. Output is wherever the formula is.

Straightforward use of a built-in.

---

If the output has to be an array even though the input isn't, the formula grows to 55 bytes.

```
=LET(a,SUBSTITUTE(A1,"00",0),MID(a,SEQUENCE(LEN(a)),1))
```

---

If the output has to be an array but it can have trailing empty space, it's 47 bytes.

```
=MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"00",0),SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1)
```

Comment: Drop the `"`s around the third argument for -2 bytes

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
\0d0V
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiXFwwZDBWIiwiIiwiMTAwMTAwMVxuMTExIl0=)

-1 thx to @Steffan

Comment: `\`00\`` => `‛00` (or `\0d`)

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 5 bytes

```
`000v
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWSxMMDAzKlhQnJRdDRRbsVzI0NASKGhiCaRAyROIoQZQBAA)

##### Explanation

```python
`000v  # Implicit input
`00    # Push "00"
   0   # Push 0
    v  # Replace "00" with "0"
       # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 4 bytes

```
ĭZĬ‼
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6FiuOrI06suZRw54lxUnJxVDBBTd7ow11DIAQSsZyAfkwEexicBZUHETD1AFpmChYFUIPii0opiHJxEJcBQA)

```
ĭZĬ‼        Take [1,0,0,1,0,0,1] as an example
ĭ       Uninterleave
            [1,0,0,1,0,0,1] -> [1,0,0,1] [0,1,0]
 Z      Check non-zero
            [0,1,0] -> [Failure,1,Failure]
  Ĭ     Interleave
            [1,0,0,1] [Failure,1,Failure] -> [1,Failure,0,1,0,Failure,1]
   ‼    Remove failures
            [1,Failure,0,1,0,Failure,1] -> [1,0,1,0,1]
```

The idea is to remove all zeros at odd positions (0-based).

The code makes use of the fact that Nekomata is lazy: `Z` will not fail immediately when it sees a zero, but only replace it with a "failure", that is, a nondeterministic object that has no value. Lists that contain failures can be used in most operations just like normal lists, and will only fail when they are printed as the final result. So we can safely interleave it with the original even-indexed part, and then remove all failures.

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 191 bytes

```
string a(string s){var l=(s+'1').ToCharArray();s="";int b=0;for(int i=0;i<l.Length;i++){if(l[i]=='1'){if(b>0){s+=new string('0',b/2);b=0;}s+=l[i];}else b++;}return s.Substring(0,s.Length-1);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cs-mono#fY8xT8MwEIX3/IpTlthyCTarCVLVtUxFYqg62MVNTzIO8jlFVZTfHmKagYVO907v7nt6PWFoYXel5D51cfSGCNZDQckkPE6UYrYNWwTx4WIi@IaRqFTF67duczZxHaO5Mq6pKUuNIYFtpD51kWWNs8ZnX29daNNZoxB8wBPzezw0TYbkzb5IPpBogvuGWxarZLWyj09cZ9g4e/lDj86TAyuEHqNLfQxA9a63y49c0ZLzoLgep6/eejzCrQ1cOvyAV4NhqbM/gInt3KkA2HSBOu/q94jJbTE4ZlippFQl5/pfPx9Iee/kvqsyYWaohfQ71F/sWIzTDw)

It's neither clean nor short, but it works.

Takes input as a contiguous string of characters, outputs in the same format

Explanation:

```
string a(string s){                  //Define method a that takes input string s and returns a string
  var l=(s+'1').ToCharArray();       //Add a 1 to the end of s and split into char array l
  s="";                              //Empty s
  int b=0;                           //Initialize int b with value 0
  for(int i=0;i<l.Length;i++){       //Loop through l
    if(l[i]=='1'){                   //If current char is 1
      if(b>0){                       //If b is not 0
        s+=new string('0',b/2);      //Add half the amount of 0s we've counted to s
        b=0;                         //Reset b
      }                              //End if b is not 0
      s+=l[i];                       //Add current char to s
    }                                //End if current char is 1
    else b++;                        //If current char is not 1, increment b
  }                                  //End loop
  return s.Substring(0,s.Length-1);  //Return string minus last char
}                                    //End method
```

#### Note

Yes I am aware this could simply be done using `s.Replace("00","0")`, my aim was to avoid using the obvious solution. After all, the whole point of PPCG is to have fun, right? ;)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder That's not true. This is about as golfed as you can get without using the language's built-in `Replace`

I'm using C# so I'm under no delusions about getting the shortest possible code, especially with languages like Jelly around, so might as well have a little fun in the process.

Comment: of course fun is important as well. I apologise for the comment above and I must admit I liked your answer myself (the technique you used).

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder no hard feelings, ultimately we're all here to have fun and flex our otherwise useless ability to compress code as much as possible ;)

Comment: You can do _a lot_ shorter than this without replace! `string a(string s){var r="";for(int i=0;i<s.Length;i+=50-s[i])r+=s[i];return r;}`   (looks like this is basically the C answer)

Answer (score 1):

## Swift - 65 bytes

```swift
func g(a:String){print(a.replacingOccurrences(of:"00",with:"0"))}
```

Usage: `g(a:"100100")`, obviously the I/O method is through strings.

Comment: You can save a bunch of bytes using a closure: `{$0.replacingOccurrences(of:"00",with:"0")}`. Swift 5.7 added a bunch of string processing utilities and maybe one of those is shorter yet, but I recognize they didn't exist when you wrote this.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 8 bytes

```
:z"00"\0
```

[Try-it link.](//pyth.herokuapp.com?code=:z%2200%22%5C0&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1001001%0A110011001%0A11001110011%0A111%0A001%0A00%0A11100001111001001100111100100)

Explanation:

```
:z"00"\0 Takes unquoted contiguous 1-line input.
 z       Initialized to unevaluated first input line (Q won't be any shorter)
  "00"   Matching regex pattern /00/g
      \0 Substitution string "0"
:        Regex find-and-replace
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5 8 + 1 (for -p flag) = 9 bytes

```
s/00/0/g
```

I made another answer because I liked my first one too much :)

Comment: I count 8 Bytes (+1 for the fag = 9)

Comment: @Kevin You're right.  Must have miscounted.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

## Awk - 18 bytes

First try doing anything with Awk so it might be possible to golf it more.

```
{gsub(00,0);print}
```

Usage: `echo "1001001" | awk '{gsub(00,0);print}'`

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, <s>84</s> 68 bytes

Not nearly as short as xnor's answer, but that's okay. I wanted to use `del`.

```python
L=input()
i=0
while i<len(L):
 if L[i]<1:del L[i]
 i+=2-L[i]
print L
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#K7ZVUlL672ObmVdQWqKhyZVpa8BVnpGZk6qQaZOTmqfho2nFpZCZpuATnRlrY2iVkpoDZgLFtG2NdMHMgqLMvBIFn/9Ag6BaDa1SK1KTFYr/RxvqGAAhlIzlAvJhItjF4CyoOIiGqQPSMFGwKoQeFFtQTEOSiQUA)

Comment: [73 bytes](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#K7ZVUlL672ObmVdQWqKhyZVpW2VrwFWekZmTqpBpk5Oap@GjacWlUBVna6jrE50Za52pDWRVcSlkpilUWaWk5iiARbkKijLzShR8/gNNg@o2tEqtSE1WKP4fbahjAIRQMpYLyIeJYBeDs6DiIBqmDkjDRMGqEHpQbEExDUkmFgA)

Comment: [68 bytes](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#K7ZVUlL672ObmVdQWqKhyZVpa8BVnpGZk6qQaZOTmqfho2nFpZCZpuATnRlrY2iVkpoDZgLFtG2NdMHMgqLMvBIFn/9Ag6BaDa1SK1KTFYr/RxvqGAAhlIzlAvJhItjF4CyoOIiGqQPSMFGwKoQeFFtQTEOSiQUA)

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 12 bytes

```
s.e?sbb*%k2b
```

[Try this](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s.e%3Fsbb%2a%25k2b&input=%221001001%22&debug=0)

Takes a quoted string.

I know there's a shorter Pyth answer already, but I thought someone might find this approach interesting/useful.

#### Explanation

```
s.e?sbb*%k2b
 .e         Q  # enumerated map on the implicit input string. b=element; k = position
   ?sb         # Is that character nonzero? (Done by converting char to int.)
      b        # If yes, just return that character
        %k2    # Mod 2 of the position: 0 if even 1 if odd
       *   b   # Take b that many times: "" if even, "0" if odd
s              # Concat everything.
```

So every even "0" gets replaced by "".

#### Similar, 13 bytes (12 bytes if it weren't for Pyth's unfortunate naming of map variables):

```
s.e?+%k2sbb""
```

[Try that](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s.e%3Fsbb%2a%25k2b&input=%221001001%22&debug=0)

Comment: The other takes in string so it isn't interesting, and this one can potentially take in a list...

Answer (score 1):

### CJam, <s>20</s> 18 bytes

```
1l~]e`2/z~2ff/]z:~
```

Expects input as a list of bits, separated by spaces.

Explanation:

```
1   e# Push 1:              | 1
l   e# Read line:           | 1 "1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1"
~   e# Evaluate:            | 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1
]   e# Wrap stack in array: | [1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1]
e`  e# Run-length encode:   | [[3 1] [2 0] [3 1] [2 0] [2 1]]
2/  e# Group by 2:          | [[[3 1] [2 0]] [[3 1] [2 0]] [[2 1]]]
z   e# Transpose:           | [[[3 1] [3 1] [2 1]] [[2 0] [2 0]]]
~   e# Unpack array:        | [[3 1] [3 1] [2 1]] [[2 0] [2 0]]
2ff/ e# Divide each by 2:   | [[[3 1] [3 1] [2 1]] [[1 0] [1 0]]]
]   e# Wrap stack in array: | [[[[3 1] [3 1] [2 1]] [[1 0] [1 0]]]]
z   e# Transpose:           | [[[3 1] [1 0]] [[3 1] [1 0]] [[2 1]]]
:~  e# Unpack each:         | [[3 1] [1 0] [3 1] [1 0] [2 1]]
e~  e# RLE decode:          | [1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1]
(;  e# Delete last element: | [1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1]
e# Implicit output: "110111011"
```

#### Alternative (9 bytes):

```
l~[0_]/0*
```

Expects input as a CJam list literal.

Explanation:

```
l~   e# Read line and eval: | [1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1]
[0_] e# Push [0 0]:         | [1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1] [0 0]
/    e# Split array:        | [[1 1] [1 1 1] [1 1]]
0*   e# Join with 0:        | [1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

## ES7, 23 bytes

```
_=>_.replace(/00/g,`0`)
```

Input is string without whitespace + it allows odd lengths of runs of 0, it just keeps it as is.

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 13 bytes

```sh
<<<${1//00/0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P/fxsZGpdpQX9/AQN@g9v///4aGhgZAYAimQcgQiQMA)

Answer (score 1):

## x86-16 machine code, 15 bytes

```
00000000: b401 aca8 0175 04f6 dc78 01aa e2f4 c3    .....u...x.....
```

Listing:

```
B4 01       MOV  AH, 1          ; set zero run counter flag set to positive 
        CLOOP: 
AC          LODSB               ; load next byte 
A8 01       TEST AL, 1          ; is a 1 or 0? 
75 04       JNZ  IS_ONE         ; if 1, store to output and loop 
F6 DC       NEG  AH             ; flip sign of zero run counter flag 
78 01       JS   ODD_ZERO       ; if negative, don't output 
        IS_ONE: 
AA          STOSB               ; copy char to output 
        ODD_ZERO: 
E2 F4       LOOP CLOOP          ; loop until end of input 
C3          RET                 ; return to caller
```

Callable function, input array at `[SI]`, len in `CX`.  Output to array at `[DI]`.

Test program output:

[image]

[Try it online!](http://twt86.co/?c=voAArYrI4xFJvykB6AsAuikBsCSqtAnNIcO0AayoAXUE9tx4Aari9MMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=)

Comment: [11](https://pastebin.com/KT4JCTiu)

Answer (score 1):

## [Brainfuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck), 51 bytes

```
+[,[>+>+<<-]>>[.>+++++++[<------->-]<[,>]]<[<+>-]<]
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fO1on2k7bTtvGRjfWzi5az04bAqJtdCHATjfWJlrHLhZI2miDOLH//xsaGEAQkAACKBMCDA0B)

This program takes a string of `0`'s and `1`'s as input and prints a string of `0`'s and `1`'s as output.

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 bytes

```
σD;0;0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//3yzi7WBtcH///@jDXUMdQyAEE7HAgA)

#### Explanation

```
σD;0;0
σ       replace all                 with
 D                  2 copies of
  ;0                            [0]
    ;0                                   [0]
```

Comment: 5: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@HOBeebXawN/v//H22oY6hjAIRwOhYA "Husk – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 21 bytes

```
a->[i|i<-q=a,i||q=!q]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmD7P1HXLjqzJtNGt9A2USezpqbQVrEw9n9iQUFOpUaigq6dQkFRZl4JkKkE4igppGkkamrqKERHG@oYACGUjAWKGMI4uAThLJgEmAFXCmTAJcAqEfpQ7EIxEUkmNlbzPwA)

Answer (score 1):

## APOL, 33 bytes

`j(ƒ(i ¿(!(I(∋)) ¿(≐(∈) 0 '') 1)))`

Explanation:

```
j(            Join list to string
  ƒ(          List-builder for
    i         Get input
    ¿(        Returning if
      !(      Not
        I(    As number
          ∋   Loop item
        )
      )
              If true return
      ¿(      Returning if
        ≐(∈)  Loop counter is even
        0     If true return 0
        ''    Else return an empty string
      )
      1       Else return 1
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [convey](http://xn--wxa.land/convey/), 32 bytes

```
{">>>v
 "+."@}
1#,0=]
^>@<<
^<$1
```

[Try it online!](https://xn--wxa.land/convey/run.html#eyJjIjoie1wiPj4+dlxuIFwiKy5cIkB9XG4xIywwPV1cbl4+QDw8XG5ePCQxIiwidiI6MSwiaSI6IlsxLDEsMSwwLDAsMCwwLDEsMSwxLDEsMCwwLDEsMCwwLDEsMSwwLDAsMSwxLDEsMSwwLDAsMSwwLDBdIn0=)

How it works with input [1,0,0,0,0,1]:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 23 bytes

```
,[.++[->+++++<]>+[,>],]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fJ1pPWzta104bBGxi7bSjdexidWL//zc0MIAgIAEEUCYEGBoCAA)

```
,[         while(c=getchar()) {
  .++[       putchar(c);
    ->+++++< e=5*(c+2)
  ]
  >+[        if(e!=-1) {
    ,>         getchar();
  ]          }
,]         }
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Lexurgy](https://www.lexurgy.com/sc), 10 bytes

Input is a string of `a`s and `b`s, where `a` is 1 and `b` is 0.

Finds two `b`s and replaces them with a `b` and an empty string.

```
a:
b b=>b *
```

Variant that does the same thing with actual `0` and `1` digits (12 bytes):

```
a:
\0\0=>\0 *
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 28 bytes

```
f(L)=L[(L-1)^{[0...9999]}<1]
```

Takes input as a list of 0s and 1s, and returns a list of 0s and 1s.

This works by filtering for elements that are either 1, or 0 and with odd (0-based) index in the list.

Desmos lists have a maximum length of 10000 elements, so `[0...9999]` is a valid golf from `[0...L.length]`.

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/s2ifx77buy)

Answer (score 1):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 8 bytes

```
$0||NR%2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v9fxaCmxi9I1ej/fwMuAy5DMDSAQkMA)

I found this nice solution following the thinking of [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/118774/99944).

It's a simple OR gate used as a AWK pattern: it prints the line if the input is true (i.e., `1`) or it's an odd line (`NR` is the number of the line). It will skip only the `0` in even lines.

#### [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 15 bytes (former answer)

```
gsub("00","0")1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v8/vbg0SUPJwEBJR8lASdPw/39DQ0MuAwNDEDAAAyDFBaIB)

Globally substitutes all `"00"` strings to `"0"`. The `1` in the end is a True token to force printing the line if there were no substitutions.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org), 21 bytes

```
!x=replace(x,"00"=>0)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZZBBDoIwEEXjlhu4G1i1CZKycwM38ASGRZWSFJtKChhO4CXcsMEbeBhdehIrBSzYpu3Mn9eZaW9dXgtO27arq2yzfbhNpFgh6JGhxvcI8aKYYBN7nrKzAg5cgmI0FVyyEmEH9KD-ASJgFyoCtGMVDQqqShagshC8QtwH7329exgbutFsfuYSUeMXistKSKT1GNwGO0ympmT7Wq33oU_0HPYEdCbotX4ljrZHYsmEk7rkJuuPHc6Bt-Nfzc5PRmX0xzt97l-lWf-zHqyIXWdBWK-wtcR80Qc)

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 22 bytes

```
Select[#>=(i=-i)&]
i=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7Pzg1JzW5JFrZzlYj01Y3U1MtlivT1vB/QFFmHlBU1y7NQTlWrS44OTGvrpqr2lDHAAihZK0OSAAmhEMQzoJJgBlwpUAGXAKsEqEPxS4UE5Fkarlq/wMA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 25 bytes

```matlab
@(a)a(~mod(cumsum(~a),2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z@mYKugp6f330EjUTNRoy43P0UjuTS3uDRXoy5RU8dIU/N/mka0oY4BEELJWE0usBBMEImFkIIykTQAmUjSYB0I/SgWoJiMJBOr@R8A)

Find the indices of even elements in the cumsum of the logical negation of the input.

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 4 [bytes](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=U0JDUyDihpAgK0BcMOKKlwpEZWNvZGUg4oaQIOKHjOKKjy0x4pa9wrEu4o2Y4ouv4oav4oqCwq8x4qe74ouv4qe7LOKHjOKItSjihpjCrzHii68rMjU2KSAtQFwwKzEKJnAg4oqCIjggYml0IGVuY29kaW5nOlx0IiBTQkNTICLih4ziio8tMeKWvcKxLuKNmOKLr-KGr-KKgsKvMeKnu-KLr-Knuyzih4ziiLUo4oaYwq8x4ouvKzI1NikiIOKKgitAXDDih6ExMjkiLiziiLY74oiYwqzCscKv4oy14oia4peL4oyK4oyI4oGFPeKJoDziiaQ-4omlKy3Dl8O34pe_4oG_4oKZ4oan4oal4oig4qe74paz4oeh4oqi4oeM4pmt4ouv4o2J4o2P4o2W4oqa4oqb4oqd4pah4oqU4omF4oqf4oqC4oqP4oqh4oav4oaZ4oaY4oa74per4pa94oyV4oiK4oqXL-KIp1xc4oi14omh4oi64oqe4oqg4o2l4oqV4oqc4oip4oqT4oqD4oqZ4ouF4o2Y4o2c4o2a4qyaJz_ijaPijaQh4o6L4oas4pqCzrfPgM-E4oiefl9bXXt9KCnCr0AkXCLihpB8IyIKJnAg4oqCImRlY29kZWQ6XHQiIERlY29kZSAiwqPCsS0xwrjChy7DjMKlwrPCsMKIMcKfwqXCnyzCo8K_KMK1wogxwqUrMjU2KSIg4oqCK0BcMOKHoTEyOSIuLOKItjviiJjCrMKxwq_ijLXiiJril4vijIrijIjigYU94omgPOKJpD7iiaUrLcOXw7fil7_igb_igpnihqfihqXiiKDip7vilrPih6HiiqLih4zima3ii6_ijYnijY_ijZbiipriipviip3ilqHiipTiiYXiip_iioLiio_iiqHihq_ihpnihpjihrvil6vilr3ijJXiiIriipcv4oinXFziiLXiiaHiiLriip7iiqDijaXiipXiipziiKniipPiioPiipnii4XijZjijZzijZrirJonP-KNo-KNpCHijovihqzimoLOt8-Az4TiiJ5-X1tde30oKcKvQCRcIuKGkHwjIg==)

```
▽\=.
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAg4pa9XD0uCgpmIFsxIDAgMCAxIDAgMCAxXQpmIFsxIDEgMCAwIDEgMSAwIDAgMV0KZiBbMSAxIDFdCmYgWzAgMCAxXQpmIFswIDBdCmYgWzEgMSAwIDAgMCAwIDAgMCAxIDFd)

Port of emanresu A's [Vyxal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/261902/97916).

```
▽\=.
   . # duplicate
 \=  # scan by equality
▽    # keep
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 5 50 + 1 (for -p flag) = 51 bytes

```
@a=split'',$_;splice@a,$i++,!$_ for@a;$_=join'',@a
```